# Scrollview isn't working in y-axis

Tags: jquery, scrollview

This jQuery plugin doesn't work with the y-axis.

http://jsfiddle.net/weissraum/tsyzZ/

How can this be solved?

You cannot delete doctype declaration in jsfiddle, but I did successfully locally on both x & y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your CSS so that the `#container` element is 100% of the size of the view-port, not 100% of the size of the document.

Add this to the `#container` CSS rule:

```
position : absolute;
top      : 0;
left     : 0;
```

That's all, the issue was that the `#container` element didn't have any vertical scrollbars since it was full document height.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tsyzZ/3/

Also, if you change `overflow:auto` to `overflow:hidden` for the `#container` element the scrollbars will disappear but the user can still use the `scrollview` plugin to pan the element.